# Array of Json indexing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Having such an object

```
obj = [{id:1, val:"blabla"}, {id:2, val:"gnagna"}]
```

How can we index `obj` with `id` like `obj[id==1]` (Pandas Pythonic way).

I assume the followings:

1. Objects inside the array all have ids.
2. The first appearing id that matches is taken, assuming other objects matching are equal.

Comment: Your question lacks precision. Consider editing it by adding context, code, etc ... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean with "index it"? Do you want to access the objects (e.g. `{id:1, val:"blabla"}`) by their id?

Comment: you do `obj[0]->id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find an item on a specific condition, defined in the callback.

The callback in this case would be

```
function f(i){return i.id === 1}
```

or using an arrow function:

```
i => i.id === 1
```

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  val: "blabla"
}, {
  id: 2,
  val: "gnagna"
}]

var item = obj.find(i => i.id === 1);
console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find` method for that. `obj.find( o => o.id == index)`

```js
obj = [{id:1, val:"blabla"}, {id:2, val:"gnagna"}] 

function getBy(index){
return obj.find( o => o.id == index)
}

console.log(getBy(1))
console.log(getBy(2))
```

Comment: `find` as there will be only one element.